# React native LayoutAnimation disable

Tags: react-native, layout-animation

I have these code:

```
LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
this.setState({dragonTypes: res.body.dragonTypes});
```

and my problem is: when the **res.body.dragonTypes** is empty, these is nothing happen, it's right but when i do some others, the LayoutAnimation still work and sometimes make it very weird. especially during transition. so can i clear LayoutAnimation manually or how to use it right?

Thx a lot.